# Car affordability

Tags: car, financing

New here. So. To start, I am a HUGE car head- so finding an affordable car is not really the aim here. I am 23 and a ~somewhat~ recent college grad. I have been blessed with an amazing job and manage to pull in around 4300 a month net. I currently drive a 2018 sedan and owe around 10000 on it. The trade value on that vehicle is around 22-23k so net equity is around 12k. I decided that I wanted to upgrade(I have been driving the 18 model for a yr) I also have around 13-15k cash saved up to put down.I have a few thousand saved up for emergencies too. The car I am looking at is used as well and costs around 46k. My plan would be to put down 12k and trade my current vehicle and I would finance the rest. I have also prequalified for a few loans at an ~unfortunate~ 8% interest rate no doubt due to my limited credit history. My credit score is above 700 as well! I am simply asking if this is a reasonable option for me. I have owned my current vehicle less than a year but decided that I wanted to own the higher trim level! Please let me know if I need to expand

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you explain what you mean by "a HUGE car head".  Do you want a car that is new(ish) and seen as a status symbol, or one that you think is fun to drive?  For the latter, I have a lot more fun with my '02 Miata (purchased used for well under $5K) than I would with any newer car I can think of.

Comment: You will need to be more specific what your actual question is. This is to open ended to get a meaningful answer.

Comment: Yes, we need to know what you would like to get advise for. How to find a cheaper car? How to get a cheaper loan? Comming up with a refinancing plan? Whether or not it is a good idea to do this?

Comment: Welcome! Please help us out: you chose "Car affordability" as the title of your question, but then your question says "finding an affordable car is not really the aim here". What would you like opinions on? My opinion is that spending $46k on a car is not a good choice for a $51.6k net annual income.

Comment: More or less trying to find out if this is a good idea! What I mean’t by “car affordability” and I see how this was poorly worded, was if I could afford this? I have calculated that if I put the cash down on the car (which including my trade in would be right around 22,000) I could afford the monthly payments and have a decent interest rate without going past a 60 month period. 48 is optimal but isn’t affordable when you factor gas and insurance premiums in the equation. Based off of the 20% rule I could spend around $650 net of my projected insurance and gas costs.

Comment: Also plan on buying the vehicle 3-4 years old to aboud those crazy first 3 years of depreciation. For maintenance the car comes with a factory warranty for 50,000 miles and covers everything OEM on the vehicle. The vehicle is an Alfa Romeo Giulia QV. It is definitely for fun. I do not care about status really, but just want a car that I can look at, admire, and buzz around in. Thanks everyone and sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @Jcremer24, if you edit your question with more specific asks, it can be reopened and more people will probably add answers with their opinions, but for a question like yours, all we can really give is opinions; there is no hard and fast rule on what is "allowed" or "right". Personally, I think you would be tying up too much of your hard-earned savings and committing too much of your future income to a car. You seem too focused on what monthly payment you can afford, even after depleting your savings. But, you don't need my permission. :) Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

What exactly are you asking?

The best advice I can give you is to buy a car you can actually afford and to save/invest the money you'd spend on financing the car.

I don't know the terms of the loan but chances are you'll end up paying more interest than the car is worth, especially if you consider that a car's value depreciates rapidly (some sources say it could lose 50% of it's value within the first three years).

You also need to factor in gas, insurance, and maintenance.